# How do I specify additional include and lib directories when compiling/configuring? (re: autoconf/configure)

Tags: compilation, include, configure, lib

I'm a Windows developer with only a little experiencing compiling with GNU gcc/make/autoconf, etc.

I'm trying to compile some applications on my new MacBook and I'm placing the dependencies in a separate directory:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/ports
make
make install
```

Now when I compile/configure an application that requires a dependency located in /opt/ports, how do I specify that?  (ie. lib and include directories)

Answer (score 0):

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/sw/include/'
export LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/'
```